# Python BFS with collections

Tags: python, graph, breadth-first-search

I came across a [BFS code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576675-bfs-breadth-first-search-graph-traversal/) which involves collections and deques but I could not understand it much. I hope some of the pythonistas here can help a n00b out.

```
from collections import deque

def bfs(g, start):
    queue, enqueued = deque([(None, start)]), set([start])
    while queue:
        parent, n = queue.popleft()
        yield parent, n
        new = set(g[n]) - enqueued
        enqueued |= new
        queue.extend([(n, child) for child in new])
```

Questions:

1) The |= operator seems to be related to bitwise operations - I have no idea how it relates to a BFS, any hints?

2) *popleft()* should return only one value from what I understand, so how is it returning parent and n here?

3) Is *new* the series of nodes visited? If I want the nodes, do I just keep appending them to a list?

Thanks in advance.

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `a |= b` for sets is the same
   as `a = a.union(b)`.
2. `popleft()` does indeed return
   only one element, which happens to
   be a 2-tuple, and therefore can be
   unpacked into two values.
3. `new` is the set of not yet
   visited nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your last question: the piece of code you have there is a *generator*, which means it yields nodes as it traverses the graph breadth-first. It doesn't do any actual searching, it just traverses the node for you. The way you use this piece of code is by iterating over the result, which will give you all nodes in turn (in breadth-first order):

```
for parent_node, node in bfs(my_graph):
    if node == needle:
        break
```

Or if you want, for example, a list of all nodes that match a particular condition:

```
nodes = [ node for parent_node, node in bfs(my_graph) if condition(node) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

`x |= y` sets x to the boolean OR of x and y. `set` overrides the operator to mean the set union. Basically, it's a fancy way of writing `enqueued.update(new)`.

2)

The first element of `queue` is always a 2-tuple.

```
tpl = (a,b)
x,y = tpl
```

is a fancy way of writing

```
tpl = (a,b)
assert len(tpl) == 2
x = tpl[0]
y = tpl[0]
```

3)

`new` is just a temporary variable for - well - the new(unvisited) nodes. `enqueued` contains the result.